# How can I enrich objects stored in a terraform dictionary?

Tags: terraform

## What I'm Trying

```json
locals {
  source-map = {
    foo = {
        name = "George"
    },
    bar = {
        name = "Sally"
    }
  }

  enriched-map = [for k, v in local.source-map : {
    "${k}" = {
        name    = v.name,
        lower_name = lower(v.name)
    }}]
}

output "enriched-map" {
  value = local.enriched-map
}
```

## What I Get

```json
enriched-map = [
  {
    "bar" = {
      "lower_name" = "sally"
      "name" = "Sally"
    }
  },
  {
    "foo" = {
      "lower_name" = "george"
      "name" = "George"
    }
  },
]
```

## What I Want

```json
enriched-map = {
  "bar" = {
    "lower_name" = "sally"
    "name" = "Sally"
  },
  "foo" = {
    "lower_name" = "george"
    "name" = "George"
  }
}
```

How do I get a map as a result rather than an array?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

```json
enriched-map = { for k, v in local.source-map : 
    k => {
        name    = v.name,
        lower_name = lower(v.name)
    }
  }
```